# Resource manager global interceptor in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

I have kind of a big solution with lots of resources in it. Now I want to create an opportunity to dynamically change a particular word in resources.
I'm wondering is there a way to create a global interceptor of resource manager GET method in order to insert someting like pipe method and transform strings from resources?

Comment: You can probably override @RenderPage method... might be easier to just do it in JS... what do you mean by "resources"?

Comment: I mean *.resx files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution in this NuGet library https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony

It allows you to intercept any method before or after execution so that you can change the resulting value.

But using this approach isn't recommended if you can do it in another way. Overuse of such mechanics can make your code completely unreadable and unsupported.